# File parsing using perl

Tags: perl, parsing

I am stuck in middle , i need  help .

i have two files :

- file1:

Total X        :
Total y        :
Total z        :
Total t        :

file 2:
4790351 4786929 3422    0
84860   84860   0   0
206626  206626  0   0
93902   93823   79  0

now  i want output like this in third file

Total X        : 4790351 4786929  3422   0
   Total y        :   84860   84860     0   0
   Total z        :  206626  206626     0   0
   Total t        :   93902   93823    79   0

## This  is  my code below to try the parsing :Please help me getting the required output

```
while ( not eof $tata and not eof $outfh )
 {
   my @vals1 = split /":"/,<$tata>;


   my @vals2 = split /\s+/, <$outfh>;

   my @sum = join "\t", map { $vals1,$vals2[$_]} 0 .. $#vals2;

   printf $_ for @sum,"\n";

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $FILE1, "<", "file1.txt";
open my $FILE2, "<", "file2.txt";
open my $OUTFILE, ">", "results.txt";

my $first_line = <$FILE1>;
close $FILE1;

my @line_prefixes = split /\s*:\s*/, $first_line;

while (my $line = <$FILE2>) {
    print {$OUTFILE} "$line_prefixes[$. - 1]: $line";
}

close $FILE2;
close $OUTFILE;
```

`$.` is the current line number in the file (`$.` equals 1 for the first line).

A sample run:

```
/pperl_programs$ cat file1.txt
Total X : Total y : Total z : Total t :

~/pperl_programs$ cat file2.txt
4790351 4786929 3422 0
84860 84860 0 0
206626 206626 0 0
93902 93823 79 0

~/pperl_programs$ cat results.txt

~/pperl_programs$ perl myprog.pl

~/pperl_programs$ cat results.txt
Total X: 4790351 4786929 3422 0
Total y: 84860 84860 0 0
Total z: 206626 206626 0 0
Total t: 93902 93823 79 0
~/pperl_programs$
```

For your altered files:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $FILE1, "<", "file1.txt";
open my $FILE2, "<", "file2.txt";
open my $OUTFILE, ">", "results.txt";

chomp(my @line_prefixes = <$FILE1>);
close $FILE1;

while (my $line = <$FILE2>) {
    print {$OUTFILE} "$line_prefixes[$.-1] $line";
}

close $FILE2;
close $OUTFILE;
```

Sample output:

```
~/pperl_programs$ cat file1.txt
Total X :
Total y :
Total z :
Total t :

~/pperl_programs$ cat file2.txt
4790351 4786929 3422 0
84860 84860 0 0
206626 206626 0 0
93902 93823 79 0

~/pperl_programs$ cat results.txt

~/pperl_programs$ perl 1.pl

~/pperl_programs$ cat results.txt
Total X : 4790351 4786929 3422 0
Total y : 84860 84860 0 0
Total z : 206626 206626 0 0
Total t : 93902 93823 79 0
```

If your files are big, you probably don't want to read the whole first file into memory.  If that's the case, you can read each file line by line:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $FILE1, "<", "file1.txt";
open my $FILE2, "<", "file2.txt";
open my $OUTFILE, ">", "results.txt";

while (!eof($FILE1) and !eof($FILE2) ) {
    my $line_prefix = <$FILE1>;
    chomp $line_prefix;

    my $numbers_line = <$FILE2>;
    chomp $numbers_line;
    my @numbers = split /\s+/, $numbers_line;

    my $fifth_column = $numbers[1] / $numbers[0];
    say {$OUTFILE} "$line_prefix $numbers_line $fifth_column";
}

close $FILE1;
close $FILE2;
close $OUTFILE;
```

Comment: Hi stud ...actually  file 1 don't have all labels  in single  line .... Total x  then Total y in new line and so on....So your code  is  printing first line  of  file 1 till  first split

Comment: @Volverine, I added an example for your new input files.

Comment: @stud ..thanks it worked ...i have  one more query ... suppose i want to divide  column 2 value with value  column value 3  and print  it in last  column new to add (5th column) ..how can we do that...for  example                                                     Total X : 4790351 4786929 3422 0 0.99 ( same for rest too ). can you please help for that  too

Comment: @Volverine, `Illegal division by zero`.  But generally,   `my @numbers = split /\s+/, $line;  my $fifth_column = $numbers[1] / $numbers[2]; print {$OUTFILE} "$line_prefixes[$.-1] $line $fifth_column";`

Comment: @stud my output is  coming like below                                                               
Total Z       : 2135943 2135943 0 0     
Total Y       : 420512 420512 0 0     
Total X        : 0 0 0 0                                                                   can we allign the output like below                                                               Total Z       : 2135943 2135943 0 0     
Total Y       :   420512    420512 0 0     
Total X       :           0                    0 0 0

Comment: @Volverine, Try this: `printf "%-10s %10d %10d %2d %2d  %8.4f\n", "hello :", 44444, 333333, 0, 0, 0.998777889897;`

Answer (score 0):

Your specification has a few loose ends; for instance - what if there are more lines in `file2` then there are total labels in `file1`?  Do you want the spaces in the first input file ignored?  Do you want the spaces in the output file specifically as shown? ... and you really don't want any totals calculated??

I've presumed "yes" to most of these questions.  My solution is driven by the second data file - which means that if there are more total labels then there are lines of data, they are going to be ignored.  It also means that if there are more data lines in file2 then there are labels in file1, the program will simply make up the label - `No Label?`.

Finally, just in case you want to add these numbers up at some point, I've included but commented the `sum` function from `List::Util`.

```
use v5.12;
use File::Slurp;
# use File::Util qw( sum );

my $file1 = "file1.txt";
my $file2 = "file2.txt";
my $file3 = "file3.txt";

open(my $outfh, '>', $file3) or die "$file3: $!";

my @vals1 = split /\s*:\s*\n/ , read_file($file1);
my @vals2 = read_file($file2);

while (my $line = shift @vals2) {
    chomp $line;
    # my $total = sum split(" ", $line);
    printf $outfh  "%s : %s\n" , shift @vals1 // "No Label?" , $line ;
}
#
# $ cat file3.txt
Total X : 4790351 4786929 3422 0
Total y : 84860 84860 0 0
Total z : 206626 206626 0 0
Total t : 93902 93823 79 0
```

Comment: there will always we equal num of  labels   and data  in both files

Comment: Then the code shown will work fine - it only requires the `// "No Label?"` to cover the error condition so, might as well leave it there.